# EditorGUILayout.ObjectField does not recieve reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning custom editors. The `ObjectField` appears and its possible to drag `Inventory` scripts or `GameObjects` containing them to the slot. But when dropped nothing happens. The field lights up but the dropped object doesn't stick.

And when I push the button `target` is `null`.

```
public class AddInventory : EditorWindow {

    public Inventory target;

    [MenuItem("Inventory/Add items")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        GetWindow<AddInventory>("Add items");
    }

     void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Label("Add items to  inventory", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        Inventory target = null;
        target = (Inventory) EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Inventory thingy", target, typeof(Inventory), true);


        if (GUILayout.Button("I am button!"))
        {
            Debug.Log(target.thing);

        }
    }
}
```

I also tried per suggestion:

```
   void OnGUI()
{

    GUILayout.Label("Add items to  inventory", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

  var  myInventory = (GameObject) EditorGUILayout.ObjectField( myInventory, 
     typeof(GameObject), true);


    if (GUILayout.Button("I am button!"))
    {
        Debug.Log(myInventory.name);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redefining `target`. Remove the `Inventory target = null;` line from `OnGUI()` plus make sure your `Inventory` class is of course a Unity `Object` to use the `ObjectField`.

```
public class AddInventory : EditorWindow {

    public Inventory target;

    [MenuItem("Inventory/Add items")]
    public static void ShowWindow()
    {
        GetWindow<AddInventory>("Add items");
    }

     void OnGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.Label("Add items to  inventory", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

        target = (Inventory)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Inventory thingy", target, typeof(Inventory));   

        if (GUILayout.Button("I am button!"))
        {
            Debug.Log(target.thing);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lautaro Indeed, but your setting `target` to `null` just before you call the `ObjectField` so `target` will always be `null`. Have you removed that line as suggested?

Comment: This is the first way i ever tried it! But it worked some minutes before you posted the new answer. This makes most sense of course. Thanks!